# Best Tips for hadoop integrations to mysql database

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I am new to hadoop. But i have problem to me. We have almost 200k rows in every table in my mysql database. So application is very slow, for query processing. I am planning to work on hadoop. Can anyone guide me for better path to start.Is any other way to implement hadoop, without map reduce. Because my applications is already developed. So i preferred to work my sql queries. How to use map reduce code for better performance. How to convert mysql to HDFS

Comment: what are 'lakhs rows' ?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not fully clear but there are a number of **SQL tools** which are part of the Hadoop ecosystem. [Hive](https://hive.apache.org/) is the most classic one but is mainly for batch processing since it generates MapReduce code under the hood. If you want low latency responses take a look at [Impala](http://impala.io/) which is an MPP engine. Both tools run on top of HDFS. You can experiment with those tools by trying them out in a VM. There are VMs available from all major vendors: Cloudera, Hortonworks and MapR. I generally use this one: [Quickstart CDH5.3](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/downloads/quickstart_vms/cdh-5-3-x.html)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this answers your questions.

Since you have all the data in MYSQL you can use SQOOP to pull the data into HDFS and do what you want.

You can install hadoop from the scratch if you want or use VMs from Cloudera CDH4/CDH5.3 or Hortonworks Sandbox v 2.1 or 2.2 or MapR Sandbox for Hadoop.

**Installing Hadoop from scratch and Using VMs:**

This link provides both manuaal and VM installation guidelines.

https://github.com/hramkumar/hadoop_links/blob/master/Hadoop-Links.txt

**MySQL to HDFS – Using Sqoop**

- *Configuring  MySQL connector*

> NOTE: All this configuration as done using root. Use yours if you
>   don't have root privileges.

Download MySQL connector (that suits your version of MySQL I use 5.6.15.0)

If you use Hadoop on your linux machine simply copy/move the MySQL connector to /usr/lib/sqoop/lib. If you use VM on Windows, copy/move the MySQL connector to your VM first and then to /usr/lib/sqoop/lib.

```
sudo cp /home/harish/Desktop/mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar /usr/lib/sqoop/lib
```

Go to the location /usr/lib/sqoop.

```
cd /usr/lib/sqoop
```

Open Command Prompt (CMD) on Windows and check the IPv4 Address and Grant all privileges to root@your_ipv4_address. My IPv4 Address is 192.168.243.4, replace this with yours.

Type the following command on CMD.

```
ipconfig
grant all privileges on *.* to root@192.168.243.4 IDENTIFIED BY ‘root’ WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

- *Importing the table to HDFS using MySQL connector*

If you use Hadoop on your lunux machine, you will need, DB name, Table Name, Username and Output Directory. Connect to Jdbc:mysql and pull the data.

If you use VM you will need IPv4 Address, DB name, Table Name, Username and Output Directory.

command for pulling MySQL data using VM:

```
bin/sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://192.168.243.4/DATABASE_NAME --table TABLE_NAME --username root -P --target-dir /OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_NAME -m 1
```

Enter password for root and you will see Map Reduce job running.

Now, go to your HDFS output location, in case of VM the location could be:

```
http://localhost:50070/dfshealth.jsp
/OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_NAME
part-m-00000
```

the part-m-0000 file will have all your MySQL table data.